# Dagger injection for different activities

Tags: android, dagger-2

So I am learning Dagger 2 and there is one thing I dont quite follow. 
So I understand that in the component you need to specifiy the activity that can be used for injecting into:

```
Singleton
@Component(modules={AppModule.class, NetModule.class})
public interface NetComponent {
   void inject(MainActivity activity);
}
```

First of all why do I need to specify this ? (I dont ever user the variable activity).

But the main question is lets say I have 10 different activities or fragments do I need to list them all here ? Is this the correct way of doing it or perhaps could we inject into the Application ? What is the correct thing to do if I want to use the NetComponent throughout my application.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you have one supplying component for every of your activities so yes. You have to write `inject()` method for every one.

Also note, that you can't use injection in to the base class, because it will produce this error: https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/214

Good:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules={AppModule.class, NetModule.class})
public interface NetComponent {
   void inject(MainActivity activity);
   void inject(SplashActivity activity);
   void inject(AnotherActivity activity);
}
```

Bad:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules={AppModule.class, NetModule.class})
public interface NetComponent {
   void inject(BaseActivity activity);
}
```

Also if you do not want to inject, but only get your API service etc. you can not inject, but use:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules={AppModule.class, NetModule.class})
public interface NetComponent {
   SomeNetworkOrApiClass getNetworking();
}
```

And just get your networking from your component, when you need it.

Try to read this useful articles:

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Dependency-Injection-with-Dagger-2

https://github.com/konmik/konmik.github.io/wiki/Snorkeling-with-Dagger-2